# SVG opengl implementation - strokes overlap on transparency

Tags: opengl, image-processing, vector-graphics

I am trying to implement svg rendering by opengl using meshes. 
In paths with opacity less than 1, the color of overlapping strokes add up.

[image: ![enter image description here]

But it should be like this

[image]

the opengl calls are:

```
    glDepthMask(false);
    glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    ....
    glDrawArrays(....);
    ....
    glDepthMask(true);
```

is there any opengl calls, shader or other method to have same transparent value around the whole stroke without modifying the geometry of the shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the depth buffer to ensure that the second time you get on a point the pixels aren't written.

You start with the maximum depth value and each new path (that you want to add to the existing drawn image) you decrement the depth.